# $2 =\Theta (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ ; why is a constant $\Theta$ if $e$?

Tags: algorithms

This is for my Combinatorial Algorithms class. I kind of have an idea as to why a constant would equal $e$ as but I'm a bit confused when I have the statement that $2$ and $(1 + \frac{3}{n})^n$ are $\Theta$ of each other. This is pretty much saying that $2$ and $e^3$ are theta of each other? Is it because they are both constants that we can say this? Or are we analyzing these two as n $\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: What is the question? It is unclear what you mean.

Comment: There is a logical equivalence $f=\Theta(g)\iff g=\Theta(f)$. Since these asymptotic notations are always "up to multiplication by constants," we can say that $a=\Theta(b)$ for any constants $a$ and $b$. Furthermore, if $a\le f(n)\le b$, then $f=\Theta(a)=\Theta(b)$ (and further $f=\Theta(c)$ for any constant $c$).

Comment: The expression $(1+1/n)^n$ is always between $2$ and $3$.